# Why does the PyTorch tutorial on DQN define state as a difference?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I'm a master's student in EECS working my way towards understanding how DQN [0] works.

I'm working towards solving the CartPole-v0 task in as few iterations as possible.

First of all I implemented a basic Q-learning algorithm which took forever to converge, then I added decaying learning rate and experimentation proportion which made a whole lot of difference. I'm not interpreting state from the image yet, I just take an observation and discretize it to simplify things - one complication at a time.

I'm now trying to add experience replay but keep the Q-matrix approach - I will substitute it with a function-approximation ANN later. I'm wondering why the seventh code snippet in the PyTorch tutorial on DQN, the second under section "training loop" [1] is representing state as a difference between two screens. Right now I'm not doing this, and my replay memory implementation is not helping learning - quite the opposite. Of course, a good RL algorithm is independent from the representation of state and the error is probably somewhere else - especially since my Q-learning algorithm does learn if I avoid using replay memory - but this tickled my curiosity. I skimmed over the DQN paper but did not find any references to such a representation. I'll admit that I haven't read it in detail yet because I don't want to get more confused, so I might have missed it.

Is there a specific reason for this kind of representation? Does it only make sense in the context of translating an image to state?

Thanks in advance!

[0] https://doi.org/10.1038%2Fnature14236

[1] https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/reinforcement_q_learning.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that an image doesn't "represent" state -- it doesn't have information about the motion of objects in cartpole. If you don't make motion part of your state, then you don't have an MDP anymore -- it's not markov. So basically, whatever way you choose to represent "state", you have to make sure you end up with an MDP.

Presumably, taking the difference of two consecutive frames is enough to provide velocity information and make it an MDP. Stacking N frames (possibly N>2) is another common way to do this.

Comment: So it does only make sense in the context of translating an image to state! Thank you, I was so fixated on the "difference between states" that I didn't think that an image by itself is not a state!!